# Stitching together tensorflow datasets based on a probability distribution

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a dataset of paths keyed by path length. The network needs to take in paths of same length and batch process them. I am looking for a way (using the [Dataset API](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets)) to select a path length *based on the path length distribution* (as simple as `P(length) = (number of paths for this length) / (total number of paths)`, then take a batch of paths for this length. I intend to write tfrecord files (I don't think I can use the python dictionary which stores those paths directly) in separate directories (per length). How can use the Dataset API to construct queues that return me batch_size tfrecords from each directory - but choosing next directory to return from based on the path length distribution ? So I guess I can construct a Dataset for each path length as in:

```
datasets = {}
for length in path_dict.keys():
    paths_dir = '/../tfrecords/%d' % length
    filenames = [os.path.join(paths_dir, x) for x in os.listdir(paths_dir)]
    datasets[length] = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames).batch(batch_size)
```

but how do I construct a new dataset from those that selects next element from a dataset of length `x` selected based the length distribution ?

(EDIT: I probably do this wrongly, I could for instance have one tfrecord per length or something, feedback appreciated)

EDIT2: in the old APIs I could do something like:

```
def _random_filenames(tfrecords_dir, batch_size, examples):
    paths = OrderedDict()
    # tfrecords_dirs names is just the length of paths they contain
    tfrecords_dirs = sorted(map(int, os.listdir(tfrecords_dir)))
    for d in tfrecords_dirs:
        dir_ = os.path.join(tfrecords_dir, str(d))
        files = os.listdir(dir_)
        paths[d] = sorted(os.path.join(dir_, f) for f in files)
    # Calculate path statistics
    total_paths = sum(len(v) for v in paths.values())
    print('Total paths %d' % total_paths)
    stats = [(len(v) / total_paths) for v in paths.values()]
    lengths = list(paths.keys())
    filenames = []
    for j in range(0, examples, batch_size):
        pick = int(np.random.choice(lengths, p=stats))
        filenames.extend(list(np.random.choice(paths[pick], size=batch_size)))
    return filenames
```

then produce a queue from the filenames:

```
def _get_filename_queue(filenames):
    # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames,
        # epochs makes no sense here as we will just repeat the same filenames
        # shuffle even less so as we need batches of equal length
        num_epochs=None, shuffle=False, )
    return filename_queue
```

I am looking for a way to translate this into the new Dataset APIs